# In angularjs, show ng-message if email already exists based on boolean return from server.

Tags: angularjs, ajax, boolean, ng-messages

During registeration, when form submitted through ajax call and the response from the server is of boolean format.. how to handle the boolean value from the server to show ng-message indicating email already registered.. tried ng-show didn't work...

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: include more details of the issue and also some code so you can get quality answers, and to avoid removal of your post

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provided the code snippet which you are trying? angular should automatically trigger the update if defined properly. Can provide you answer once I see the code..